# Powershell script to test zip passwords from file

Tags: powershell, passwords, zip, password-recovery

I have powershell script:

```
$passwords = Get-Content list.txt
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$zipFile = ".\dane_7up.zip"
foreach ($password in $passwords)
{
    Write-Host $password
    $command = '"$7ZipPath t $zipFile -p $password"'
    iex $command
    if (-Not $?)
    {
        [console]::beep(500,300)
        return
    }
}
pause
```

I want to check if one of the passwords from list.txt file match with the zip file. But for now the script is just printing the line with 7-Zip invocation and not running it. What I should change in the script to make it working?

Also: can I escape password with "" when there is password with space in it?

Comment: Try removing the escapes around the double quotes in both `$7ZipPath` and `$command`.

Comment: This gives: Unexpected token 't' in expression or statement.

Comment: Is the letter t in `$command` supposed to be a flag? Should it have `-` in front of it?

Comment: Not a flag, a command without `-`.

Comment: Regardless, your original problem appears to be solved since Powershell is now able to attempt executing `$command`. I don't understand what the "t" is for if it is not a 7zip argument (neither does Powershell, considering the error you're getting).

Comment: No, it is not solved. The script is not testing passwords. `t` is for testing archive.

Comment: The original problem, Powershell printing `$command` and not executing it, has been resolved. There are a few other problems with what you posted, including your alignment of `-p` and `$password`. See the provided answer

Comment: You did not understood my problem exactly, but solved it. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$passwords = Get-Content "C:\path\passwords.txt"
$7ZipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zipFile = "C:\path\file.zip"
foreach ($password in $passwords)
{
    Write-Host $password
    & $7ZipPath "t" $zipFile "-p$password"
    if (-Not $?)
    {
        Write-Host $password "is not the password."
    } else {
        Write-Host $password "is the password."
    }
}
pause
```